# Large continuous virtual memory allocation on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory

Lately I came across the need to allocate a chunk of around 4GB of continuous memory (either physical or virtual) on a 64-bit Windows system which has 16GB of physical memory. I tried to allocate this buffer using new[], it threw an std::bad_alloc however. As an example the following failed:

```
char* buffer = new char[LARGE_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

When I allocate the buffer in chunks (I used 1024 bytes for a chunk), I can reach 4GB of memory however. So the following code didn't fail:

```
char** buffer = new char*[LARGE_BUFFER_SIZE/CHUNK_SIZE];
for(size_t i = 0; i < LARGE_BUFFER_SIZE/CHUNK_SIZE; ++i)
{
    buffer[i] = new char[CHUNK_SIZE];
}
```

The downside of this is that the memory isn't continuous. Is there any way using either C or C++ standard library routines or functions provided by windows I could use to allocate 4GB of continuous virtual memory?

Comment: Should be able to allocate that. Possible there was no 4 GB contiguous area left available.

Comment: The problem is most likely that there's no such large continuous area available for you. Depending on your requirements, you might try a memory-mapped file instead.

Comment: Are you building a 64 bit executable?

Comment: Oh, and please [read about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because your question is a good XY candidate: You tell us the solution you want to use and ask us for help about your solution, but you don't actually tell us what problem the solution is supposed to help you solve. There might be other solutions possible.

Comment: Be stopped at 2 GB even with the piece-wise allocation under 32 bits, @maddin45

Comment: Does `VirtualAlloc` succeed?

Comment: I'm compiling it as a 64-bit executable yes. The program I'm building is a virtual machine that emulates a physical processor, it uses the 4GB of memory as "RAM". I'll check if there was 4GB of contiguous area left, but last time I checked before I started the program there appeared to be at least 6GB of contiguous physical memory left.

Comment: Investigate using memory mapped files

Comment: Well a memory-mapped file might be useful for that, especially if you could make sure as much as possible of it is mapped into physical memory. Or you could just emulate continuous memory by implementing your own mapping. Depending on the target system you emulate the overhead of both these alternatives might be negligible.

Comment: I'll try the memory-mapped file. The emulator is designed to test code (bootloaders and OS startup) without actually running it on a physical system, performance isn't a priority in this case.

Comment: I would *guess* that Microsoft's implementation of `new` simply doesn't support 4GB allocations, even in the 64-bit library.  (I have no idea what the standard says about this.)

Comment: I compiled the code with mingw-w64 (gcc 5.1.0) with the default libstdc++ that ships with the compiler. Maybe it indeed doesn't support 4GB allocations, or allocations larger than multiple pages maybe?

Comment: It could depend on inner allocator. Try just old plain malloc.

Comment: malloc seems to have the same problem as new[]. It doesn't appear to make a difference in this case.

Comment: Then, maybe the problem in a memory heap. I would suggest to try to allocate memory with [HeapCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599(v=vs.85).aspx) and [HeapAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx). Also, you could try to figure out possibilities of your current heap, getting it with [GetProcessHeap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569(v=vs.85).aspx) and quering with [HeapQueryInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366703(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You need to specify which compiler / IDE is in use. I can, using VS2015 in a win32 console app, successfully "new" up 4 or 8GB just fine.

Comment: @Shadowwolf: difficult to say when it comes to mingw-w64, since it uses an undocumented version of Microsoft's C library.  Your best bet is to use the Windows API instead, i.e., VirtualAlloc or HeapAlloc as already suggested.

Comment: I think I'll use a combination of the windows API and memory mapped files in this case, since the user can specify the amount of virtual RAM memory to allocate. For large allocations I'll use memory mapped files, and use VirtualAlloc otherwise.